# how to remove spacing between link element and toggler in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The following code is used to make a navbar with cart icon in bootstrap 4 as shown in the image below. At the expanded state the cart is shown right of the search section. At the collapsed state in mobile devices it should align to the left of the toggler.

[image]

At the current state there is a long gap between the cart icon and the toggler as shown in the following image.

[image]

I want to achieve this.

[image]

The full code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light pr-lg-4">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <a href="#" class="moving-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 24px; margin-left: 5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>


  </div>
</nav>




    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is the css

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .moving-cart {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .moving-cart {

    margin-right:0;

  }

}
```

Live demonstration

https://codepen.io/kofhearts/pen/YjQZNM?editors=1100

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Check my answer. Your CSS code is unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- moved out that icon from nav element (which collapses at width less than 992px)
- added an id to it for styling, applied position absolute
- brought it near search button,
- when nav collapses i brought it near "Hamburger" button using Media
  Query

HTML Code Below

```
<body>
     <i id="responsive-icon" class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 24px; margin-left: 5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<nav>
..
</nav>
..
</body>
```

CSS Code:

```
#responsive-icon{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  right: 18px;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media (max-width:991px){
  #responsive-icon{
    right: 100px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `position` your `.moving-cart` as `absolute` and set the `right` as the desired space.

```
.moving-cart {
    margin-right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MBoEWB

Comment: thanks but there is a slight problem. at the collapsed state if you click on toggle button then the cart will move down.

Comment: You need to set the `top` as you desire, like: `top: 15px;`

Comment: @caivisk, you might want to put some z-index for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update below chunk of code. Just put a wrapper div in Icon and button

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light pr-lg-4">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <div>
      <a href="#" class="moving-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 24px; margin-left: 5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    
    
  </div>
</nav>
    
    
    
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write custom CSS code. You can do so by wrapping the `toggler-icon` and `shopping-cart` with an `order-last` container.

```html
<div class="order-last">
  <a href="#" class="moving-cart">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"
       style="font-size: 24px; margin-left: 5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajwLjO

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light pr-lg-4">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <div class="order-last">
        <a href="#" class="moving-cart">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"
             style="font-size: 24px; margin-left: 5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>




    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```